# Extending an embedding with trivial normal bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, cobordism

I am recently studying the book **Notes on Cobordism Theory** by *R. E. Stong* and I have noticed that the proposition below is (implicitly) used (for example to extend a $(B,f)$ structure on a boundary of a manifold on **Chapter II pag. 16**).

> **Prop.** Let $M^{m}$ and $N^{n}$ be $C^{\infty}$ compact manifold with boundary (eventually $\emptyset$) and let $j:M \to N$ be an embedding such that the normal bundle of the embedding $\nu(j)$ is trivial. Let $i$:$M \to \mathbb{R}^{r+m}$ be an other embedding with a sufficiently large $r$ then there exist an embedding $\iota: N \to \mathbb{R}^{r+n}$ such that $\iota \vert_{M} = i$.

Could you provide a reference for the proof of this proposition?

---

This question was previously asked on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103886/extending-an-embedding-with-trivial-normal-bundle) but did not receive any answer.

Comment: This looks to be an isotopy extension argument, using that Euclidean space is contractible and the weak Whitney embedding theorem.

Comment: Don't you want to use different symbols for the two embeddings you have called "j" ?

Comment: Yes, what Ryan said. And the triviality of the normal bundle is not needed. (1) if $d>2n$ then $N$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^{d}$; in fact embeddings are dense in the space of all maps, (2) Any two embeddings of $M$ in $\mathbb R^{d}$ are isotopic if $d>2m+1$; in fact isotopies are dense in the space of all smooth homotopies, (3) If two embeddings $e$ and $e'$ of $N$ become isotopic after restriction to $M$ then $e$ is isotopic to an embedding that agrees with $e'$ on $M$.

Comment: Although the proposition does not state it, you could use the trivial normal bundle assumption to strengthen the conclusion, that the normal bundle to $M$ in $N$ would be the literal pull-back of the normal bundle of one Euclidean space in another.  As Tom mentions, for the conclusion as-stated you do not need the normal bundle to be trivial.

Comment: Thanks @TomGoodwillie @RyanBudney; since I am writing my thesis and I need a citable reference for the proposition above, could you provide a precise reference? If you don't have one could you at least give me a reference for the technology that is needed?